# The late professor X gave a talk

Tags: single-word-requests, tenses

Is "the late Professor X gave a talk" correct? 
I mean: Correct not in a Zombie sort of way, but to express "Professor X gave a talk while he was still alive, which he is not any more".)

If deceased is synonym for "dead", then one should rather say
"the now late Professor X gave a talk", which sounds just wrong? 
Or do you have to say "Professor X, now deceased, gave a talk?"

Comment: No, not in my opinion.  I think "late" establishes a time reference, the person's death, and requires something explicit when you refer to a previous time.  For instance, you could say "the late Professor X once gave a talk".

Comment: @GregLee Or even *The now late Professor Cummings, once lectured on this very subject*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many internet examples of the sense 'now deceased', with an assumption of the death being recent at the time of the term first being used. For instance, one of the many hits for "the late President once" is [tidied]

> As the late President once said: “We must ask nothing but what is
>   right, and submit to nothing that is wrong."

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/late) licenses this usage:

> **late** 2 a : living comparatively recently : now deceased —used of persons  ...

Comment: Thanks. The example specifically adds "once"; this might support the comment of Greg Lee? I.e., "The late professor often gave talks" or "At that time he nursed his late mother" might be fine, while "The late professor gave a talk" or "He nursed his late mother" might be dubious?

Comment: Then there is the African English usage of "my mother is late", meaning deceased.